# How To Send Automatic Password In Terminal With Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell

I writed a bash script that install some packages but terminal ask me my sudo password which is 1 , how to send password 1 to terminal

my `script.sh` :

```
pkg install eclipse #after that ask me sudo password
pkg install virtualbox-ose
```

Comment: Can you just run `sudo script.sh` so that it's already root and doesn't require a password?

Comment: @thatotherguy but I do not want to write sudo , how can I send automatic password?

Comment: yeah but if you do this you will have to store your password somewhere... and that is maybe not what you want... You can use variables to hide it from the `history` but at a point you will still have to extract it from somewhere...
you can also modify your `sudoers` file but this may not be what you want... or you could try `sudo -i`

Comment: Did you try `echo password | pkg install <whatever>` ?

Comment: Some programs specifically use low-level terminal IO for passwords to prevent what you are trying to do.  Allowing this makes automated attacks that much easier.

Comment: Maybe a expect script?

Comment: The whole point of `sudo` is to avoid stupid tricks like this. If `pkg` genuinely uses `sudo` then `sudo` should use a cached password if you ran `sudo` recently (and the local `sudo` configuration allows this; if it doesn't, it's definitely not because they want you to store your password in a script!); if it doesn't actually use `sudo`, you have to figure out what mechanism it uses, and probably edit your question to clarify this.